# IEnumerable order by positional index

Tags: c#, sql-order-by, ienumerable

I am trying to order an IEnumerable object by an index positioning.  Example:

IEnumerable:

```
//index  1       2    3
[0] {"result1", "3", "15"}
[1] {"result2", "4", "3"}
[2] {"result3", "1", "1"}
[3] {"result4", "5", "11"}
```

I'd like to order by the 3'rd index positioning and my expected results would be this:

```
[0] {"result3", "1", "1"}
[1] {"result2", "4", "3"}
[2] {"result4", "5", "11"}
[3] {"result1", "3", "15"}
```

I've tried something like this but haven't had any luck:

```
private void UpdateGrouping(IEnumerable<List<string>> grouping)
{
    grouping.OrderBy(p => grouping.IndexOf(3));
}
```

Comment: `grouping.OrderBy(p => int.Parse(p[2]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the result, pass the grouping by ref and overwrite it inside your function:

I supose the ordering index is an integer, else change acordingly

```
private void UpdateGrouping(ref IEnumerable<List<string>> grouping)
{
    grouping = grouping.OrderBy(p => int.TryParse(p[2], out int index)?index:0);
}
```

or return the ordered list and overwrite outside your function

```
private IEnumerable<List<string>> UpdateGrouping(IEnumerable<List<string>> grouping)
{
    return grouping.OrderBy(p => int.TryParse(p[2], out int index)?index:0);
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend parsing `p[2]` to an `integer`, to avoid unexpected result with alphanumeric ordering eg. 10 smaller than 2. see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qEj7V

Comment: Uf! a linear parse inside a linq ... Ok I edit answer and use a TryParse instead

Answer (score 2):

You also can use PadLeft() to add some zeros before digits and get the sort correct.

```
    private void UpdateGrouping(ref IEnumerable<List<string>> grouping)
    {
        grouping = grouping.OrderBy(p => p[2].PadLeft(5, '0'));
    }
```

Here 5 is a sample only and for larger numbers you must use greater lengths.